# Коллтрекинг - как происходит связка с посещением?

Tags: google-analytics, яндекс-метрика, телефония

Возьмем классический вариант коллтрекинга. Есть посещение сайта, есть звонок этого посетителя по номеру, установленному на сайте.  Как происходит связка конкретного пользователя по его ID у поисковика (Яндекс, Google) с конретным вызовом этого пользователя на указанный на сайте номер? Как это происходит при динамическом коллтрекинге это понятно, в основном - каждому посетителю показывается некий уникальный номер телефона и закрепляется за ним на какое-то время. Если в течение этого времени был вызов - значит это наш посетитель. 
А как это происходит при статическом? 
В любом случае на сайт ставиться некий скрипт, который вылавливает нужные данные (видимо это может быть уникальный ID-пользователя, страница на которой пользователь и HTTP referer если удалось его определить...). С одной стороны у нас некий оператор связи у него данные по звонку, с другой наш сайт у которого данные по посещению. Скрипт с сайта передает данные оператору связи и тот уже вместе с данными о вызове передает в сервис статистики, например Яндекс?
Пытаюсь понять как технически эта связка реализуется.

Comment: При статическом этого не происходит.

Comment: А при динамике как связка происходит?

Comment: *"Как это происходит при динамическом коллтрекинге это понятно, в основном - каждому посетителю показывается некий уникальный номер телефона и закрепляется за ним на какое-то время."*

Comment: Т.е с сайта после посещения данные передаются оператору сервиса телефонии, тот их уже сопоставляет с данными по вызову , агрегирует данные с сайта и данные о звонке, передает в яндекс метрику. Так?